# Может ли быть вознагражден само-ответ на конкурсе?

Tags: поддержка, конкурс, самоответы

Составил очень хороший само-ответ, могу ли я быть вознагражден своей же репутацией?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не может. В справке написано, что репутация не возвращается автору обратно ни при каких обстоятельствах.
Ответ, если он хорош, соберет свои плюсы от других пользователей - вопрос все еще остается в списке вопросов с вознаграждением.